# Why did 実在 retain its old form when the 促音 was introduced?

Tags: words, history, style

Furthermore, are there any other words that retained their larger, pronounced つ when this change occurred?

Edit: 仏像 seems to be another one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because 在 (ざい) starts with a voiced sound (z). You usually don't see a sokuon before voiced sounds, except in gairaigo.

Comment: For a second I was going to mention 仏陀 as a counterexample but then realized it’s also technically a gairaigo 

Comment: I guess the emphasis pattern which uses sokuon (like すっごい、ひっどい etc) is the only place you’d normally see a sokuon followed by a voiced kana happen in a normal wago/kango. But that’s largely a colloquialism that’s only partially accepted in writing.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie I believe that is the only genuine exception, considering 仏壇 has regularly developed into ぶつだん.